# Click once from search suggestion

Tags: jquery, angular, search, search-suggestion

I still have to double click the suggested searches before redirecting it to its link. Recently I've added the `tabindex` for the `hide()` and `show()` methods to work

Here are my code:

```js
getSuggestion(name) {
  $('.suggestion').show();
  this.search
  .getSuggestion(name)
  .subscribe(
      name => this.results = name,
      error => alert(error),
      );
}
hide($event) {
  this.suggest = false;
}
show($event) {
  this.suggest = true;
}
showEmployee(id: string) {
  this.route.navigate(['/information/employees', id]);
  this.results = [];
}
```

```html
<section class="search-bar-wrapper" tabindex="-1" (focusin)="show($event)" (focusout)="hide($event)">
        <div class="ui right action left icon input fullwidth" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" (keyup)="getSuggestion($event.target.value)">
            <div class="suggestion" *ngIf="results.length > 0 && suggest === true">
                <div *ngFor="let result of results">
                    <div class="search-res" (click)="showEmployee(result._id)"> {{ result.name }} </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what is at lineno : 22?

Comment: can you add this code on plunkr?

Comment: Which part @Y.Hewa

Comment: the error .. {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 22,
  "colno": 29
}

Comment: @Y.Hewa: That line 22 is of the code pasted here only, that's just a syntax error but not the one which Char is talking about

Comment: oh! Then what excatly is the question ?

Comment: My question is, should I add something in the html or css for it to be clicked once for it to open to its page? @Y.Hewa

Comment: could you please make a plunker? Im finding it difficult to understand your issue ..